# How to build a Dense layer for every timestamp of a RNN and feedback every Dense's output into RNN?

Tags: keras, lstm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFxy5.png)

As the figure shows, I need to get the state of every Lstm timestamp and apply them to a dense layer for a supervised learning. Then using the output of this dense layer together with the state for next timestamp of Lstm. In general , I want to apply supervised-learning for every step of RNN and feedbackthe output to next timestamp. How can I implement this In Keras?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a combination of the [TimeDistributed](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/) wrapper on the Dense layers and the the [stateful](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/) setting in the LSTM layers. However, from the diagram you posted you don't seem to be using the output of the Dense layer for your next LTSM. Are you sure that's the case?

EDIT:

It seems like it is not possible to implement this directly in Keras, according to [this discussion](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2968). This is what they suggest:

> Basically, what you are trying to do is not possible in Keras, except by using a workaround like the one @nzw0301 suggested.
>
> The reason is that to use the output of the current timestep as input for the next one, you would basically need to go "depth-first", i.e., calculate one timestep for ALL layers, then the next timestep, and so on. What Keras does, however, is calculate ALL timesteps of ONE layer, before feeding the output into the next one.
>
> I believe there are three ways to go about this:
>
> Feed an incomplete sequence, like @nzw0301 suggested, and only look at the timestep of the output you are interested in. This is not computationally efficient, but should work.
>
> Make a custom layer. This layer would use its output at one timestep as input to the next one. However, note that this will be restricted to this single layer, i.e. you cannot apply several layers and THEN get the output this way. https://github.com/farizrahman4u/seq2seq/blob/master/seq2seq/models.py#L93 is an implementation for an old Keras version that does something like that.
>
> Use stateful RNNs (stateful=True) and make them only read one timestep at a time. Stateful means that they keep their hidden state between sequences, so it should effectively work like a "normal" RNN/LSTM, except that you only input a sequence of length 1. (Then you can interpret the output and calculate the input for the next timestep.) I never tried this way myself so far, though.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.May be my diagram is a little confusing, but I need to use  output of Dense to  LSTM layer's next step. And I don't think stateful is suitable for my case. For stateful can  know the states of the same sample index between batches, But what I need is to use output of Dense layer for the next time step of my LSTM layer in the exactly same batch and same sample. I agree with you to use    TimeDistributed wrapper, but how can I apply the output of Dense layer to the next step of LSTM?

Comment: Edited my answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That discussion is really useful.

Comment: Glad I could help!